# Amazon Relational Database Service Provisioned Storage Costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

If I use the AWS pricing calculator for an RDS, I get a price of roughly $50 per month:

[image]

When I use the service, I get a bill of roughly three times that:

[image]

What's the difference? I can't find information on what the IOPS-month of Provisioned IOPS is. The TDS suggests there is 100GB allocated, but this huge cost seems storage related. The DB is about 6GB and has no backups, so where is this cost coming from?

Comment: **Provisioned IOPS** storage is expensive -- you are paying for higher disk performance. You should probably change it to use **General Purpose SSD** (gp2 or gp3) _without_ Provisioned IOPS (io1). That should save you the $110/month. Take a look at the configuration of your RDS database and look for 'Provisioned IOPS'.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks @JohnRotenstein. You just saved me a lot of money!